# Redirect only few Kafka messages to new application to check flow is good

Tags: design-patterns, apache-kafka, architecture, throttling, consumer

I am aware of consumer group concept in kafka.

- We have `Application A` which currently takes a lot of traffic.
- We built a new `Application B` which also listens to same kafka topic.

We initially want new `Application B` to take a very small percentage of traffic like if `Application A` process 1000 messages then I want `Application B` to get 1 message and process it. That way I can check if new application processing is good before redirecting all traffic to new `Application B`.

Both applications will have diff consumer group and different db. How do we design so that new `Application B` gets only a small percentage of population and avoid duplicate processing between `Application A` and `Application B`

How to have a mechanism in Kafka to redirect only small percentage to new application?

Comment: Just to clarify, if one application has already handled a message, it shouldn't be handled by another application, correct? Therefore, processing the same message twice (once by A and once by B) is not acceptable, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: How many partitions does your topic have? How do the producers assign messages to the topic's partitions?